# how to change div background image in mouse over?

Tags: jquery, css, onmouseover

I have some set of list items like-

```
<div class="smenu">
                <ul>
                  <li ><a href="index.html"><img src="images/solution1.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
                  <li ><a href="#"><img src="images/solution2.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
                  <li ><a href="#"><img src="images/solution3.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
                  <li ><a href="#"><img src="images/solution4.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
                  <li ><a href="#"><img src="images/solution5.jpg" border="0"></a></li>                   
                </ul>
              </div>
```

**when user moves over the menu items I want to change the background image if DIV** -

```
 <div class="hbg">
        <!--here I want to display image--> 
          </div>
```

how can I do this through jQuery???

Comment: Are you saying that you want to change the class of the div when it is hovered? Your question doesn't make a lot of sense when taking in to account the 2nd code snippet. Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you intend to use the `src` of the image under the `li`.

```
$('.smenu li').mouseover( function(){
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.hbg').css('background-image', 'url(' + src + ')');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like following?

```
$('.smenu li').bind('mouseover', function(){
  $('.hbg').css('background-image', 'new image');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)  function of jquery

for example:

```
 $('.menuItem').hover( function(){ 
      $(this).css('background-image', 'image url'); 
   } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<title>UL class change on li hover</title> 

<style> 
#list {
background-color:#dda;
width:10em;
height:20em;
}

#list li {
padding:2em .5em;
}
</style>  

<ul id="list">
<li class="one">Test 1</li>
<li class="two">Test 2</li>
<li class="three">Test 3</li>
</ul>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var defaultColor = $("#list").css("background-color");

    $("#list .one").hover(
        function () { 
            $(this).parent().css({backgroundColor: "red"});
        },
        function () { 
            $(this).parent().css({backgroundColor: defaultColor});
        }
    );

    $("#list .two").hover(
        function () { 
            $(this).parent().css({backgroundColor: "green"});
        },
        function () { 
            $(this).parent().css({backgroundColor: defaultColor});
        }
    );

    $("#list .three").hover(
        function () { 
            $(this).parent().css({backgroundColor: "blue"});
        },
        function () { 
            $(this).parent().css({backgroundColor: defaultColor});
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

It would be nice to refactor this, but just replace the "color" with "image", and it should be a working solution.